# How to remove duplicate elements in a list using LINQ based on a custom condition?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm trying to eliminate all the elements in a list that obey a certain condition. Specifically, I have a list of Points and I need to filter this list such that duplicate points should be removed from the list (Note that for the purpose of this project a point that is within a certain threshold of another is considered to be the same, and hence is a duplicate). I've been trying to use LINQ to do this but I keep having Points that should have been eliminated (according to my conditions). My code is as follows:

```
var fingers = from p1Index in Enumerable.Range(0, fingAux.Count())
              from p2 in fingAux.Skip(p1Index + 1)
              let p1 = fingAux.ElementAt(p1Index)
              where (p1.X > p2.X + tresh) || (p1.X < p2.X - tresh)
              select p1;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It would really help if you'd provide a short but *complete* example demonstrating the problem...

Comment: If you want to eliminate the chance of duplicates, why not use a HashSet?

Comment: Why are you generating p1Index?

Comment: As an alternative to using a HashSet, why not use the `Distinct` operator? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.distinct(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your *code* is that you're selecting points that are more than `tresh` away from *at least one* point.

The problem with your *method* is "equality" must be commutative, meaning if `pA == pB` and `pB == pC`, then `pA == pC`.  If your condition is "points within `tresh` of each other are equal" then you have an issue, since I could have three points A, B, and C, that are within `tresh` of *each other*, but A and C are not.

e.g. if `tresh` is 5, and I have points A=3, B=7, and C=9, then A and B are "equal", B and C are "equal", but A and C are not.

Another option would be to "round" each point to the nearest `tresh` and group them, selecting the first from each group:

```
fingAux.GroupBy(p => Math.Round(p1.X / tresh))  // assuming X and/or tresh are floating-point
       .Select(g => g.First());   // take the first point of each group
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var filtered = from p in fingAux
           where !(fingAux.Any(f1 => p.X < (f1.X + tresh)) select p
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace this line:

```
where (p1.X > p2.X + tresh) || (p1.X < p2.X - tresh)
```

with this line

```
where (p1.X < p2.X + tresh) && (p1.X > p2.X - tresh))
```

Basically, if some code is doing *the exact opposite* of what you want, try inverting the operators.

Comment: Let's say you have three points 11, 12 and 15 and if my condition is that only 1 point should be taken when there are two with a difference of 1 then 11 and 15 should be selected but with the OR condition both 11 and 12 will get filtered...

Comment: @SidharthPanwar the OP stated that his code was giving only the elements he/she wanted to eliminate... Oh, I see where you are going with this. I inverted the wrong things... Morning coffee hasn't kicked in yet...

Comment: Coffee is the "Elixir of Programmers" :)